# Form-field validation via javascript with a .onclick function

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I try to do a from-field-validation via javascript on a .onclick-event. I have a form over several `<div>`'s which fade in and out when you click "further".

In the first `<div>` you write in your "name" for example. Then you click on "further" and you get to the next `<div>` where you can write down your "adress".

Here is the code how i switch the `<div>`'s:

```
document.getElementById("addnewjob_sitetwo").onclick = function(){

            // Fade out all content     

            $('#newjobcontent-siteone').fadeOut(200);

            function cutnewjobsitetwo(){

            //Cut all content out
            $('#newjobcontent-sitetwo').fadeIn(200);    
            $('#newjobcontent-siteone').css("display", "none");
            }
            setTimeout(cutnewjobsitetwo, 201);

            };
```

Now, here i modified the code of the button to get a validation of the field "jobtitle":

```
document.getElementById("addnewjob_sitetwo").onclick = function(){

            // Fade out all content 

            function validatesiteone() {
            var x = document.forms["add-new-job"].jobtitle.value;
            if (x == "") {
            alert("Name must be filled out");
            return false;
            } else {    

            $('#newjobcontent-siteone').fadeOut(200);

            function cutnewjobsitetwo(){

            //Cut all content out
            $('#newjobcontent-sitetwo').fadeIn(200);    
            $('#newjobcontent-siteone').css("display", "none");
            }
            setTimeout(cutnewjobsitetwo, 201);
            }
            }
            };
```

And here is the "form-header":

```
<form class="add-new-job" method="post" id="add-new-job" name="add-new-job">
```

And here is the field which sould get validated:

```
<input class="form-control" placeholder="Jobtitel - z.B. Rasen mähen, Malerarbeiten, etc..." id="jobtitle" name="jobtitle">
```

Sadly, when i click on the button nothing happens and even the fade doesn´t get executed. I don´t get any errors back from the chrome debugger. Can someone tell me why that doesn´t work? Thank you

Comment: Where do you call the method validatesiteone?  If you do not call the method, nothing will happen.

Comment: add a eventListener in your javascript code for clicking the button. 
e.g. $('#jobtitle').addEventListener(function(){
// YOUR_CODE_HERE
});

Comment: Add setTimeout(validatesiteone, 1); in front of the last  };

Comment: Thank you for your answers, you helped me already =)

Comment: Please post the correct answer so that other users may benefit.